# Replace loop in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a csv files with some special characters such as 'è' instead of 'é' (the csv file is in french).
So basically I referenced all the special characters and I am trying to write a code with VBA to do it. Unfortunatelly it is not working.
My code is :

```
Sub ReplaceTest()

' I referenced 35 issues

    Dim replaceWhat(35) As Variant
    Dim replaceBy(35)  As Variant
 ' This is where I reference the special caracters and link them to the good ones
    Application.Sheets("SpecialCaracters").Select
    replaceWhat(35) = Application.Range("A1:A35").Value 
    replaceBy(35) = Application.Range("B1:B35").Value

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 34
        Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Columns("A:AH").Select

        Selection.Replace What:=remplacerWhat(i), Replacement:=remplacerBy(i),  LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to change them? Shouldn't they be kept in the correct form?

Comment: Define "not working." Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you having something like this:

```
SpecialCharacters Sheet
\ | A | B
1 | à | a
2 | é | e
3 | ó | o
```

You can use the following method to iterate through all special character rows and replace the occurrences in another sheet or range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceSpecialCharacters(ReplaceRange As Range)
    Dim SpecialCharSheet As Worksheet
    Dim replaceWhat As String
    Dim replaceBy  As String
    Dim RowIndex As Long

    Set SpecialCharSheet = Sheets("SpecialCharacters")
    For RowIndex = 1 To SpecialCharSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        replaceWhat = SpecialCharSheet.Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value
        replaceBy = SpecialCharSheet.Cells(RowIndex, 2).Value

        ReplaceRange.Replace What:=replaceWhat, Replacement:=replaceBy, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next RowIndex
End Sub

Sub ReplaceSheet1()
    ' If using hard coded range
    ReplaceSpecialCharacters Sheet1.Columns("A:AH")

    ' If using Selection
    ReplaceSpecialCharacters Selection
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! it's perfectly working now. And much more flexible